# IIS (windows auth) prompts for creds on one server, not on the other

Tags: iis, kerberos

An existing Win2016 server with IIS10 prompts for creds on a simple website set up with Windows Authentication. A new server does not.

I have an existing Win2016 server running IIS. I set up a simple website with one .htm page that says Hello World. If I turn on Windows Authentication only, the browser continually prompts for username/password. I want Kerberos authentication only, so the Providers list contains Negotiate only. Enable Kernel-mode authentication is selected. The app pool is running as Network Service. The target browser is Chrome.

After many hours going nowhere with this problem, I decided to build a new box with the same spec. After setting up the site in the same way, I *do not* get prompted by the browser! Strange!

Both boxes are domain joined and seemingly have the same GPOs applied.

Can anyone advise on how I can get the first server to behave like the second? Unfortunately moving to the new box is not an option at this stage. Any help on a structured methodology for diagnosing the Kerberos exchange between server and client would be most helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: You will want to compare network traces of the prompting and non-prompting requests to make sure the second box is actually requesting and getting auth. However, the common cause is that the browser doesn't think the server is in a trusted zone so it always prompts for creds instead of quietly sending a ticket.

Comment: In the working case there is an initial 401 with www-authenticate negotiate returned. Another request is sent with a negotiate [token] and this results in a 304 to the desired webpage. In the failing case, the 401 with www-authenticate negotiate causes the request to be sent with a negotiate [token] but this results in three further 401s. It looks like that even in the failing case Kerberos is being attempted but being rejected by the server. Why would this be so?

Comment: Using Chrome, navigate to the working box web site.  Next, do the same for the non-working one.  Then run klist on the Chrome browser machine.  Do you see a Kerberos ticket for just the working box there?

Comment: Here we are. I end up with two tickets, but the non-working one has different encryption and key types.
working ==> 
KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
not working ==> KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
Session Key Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)

Comment: The failing server is receiving a ticket and it really doesn't like it which is indicative of a crypto failure, which happens when the machine/service password doesn't match what AD thinks it should be. Do you have the SPN you're trying to connect to registered to a different or multiple accounts in AD? E.g. If you've registered or re-registered it multiple times.

Comment: There's no SPN because kernel-mode authentication is turned on, on both the servers. I should add that I tried a scenario where I did create an SPN for both boxes and disabled kernel-mode authentication. In that scenario, the behaviour was the same: i.e. the working server still worked and the broken one was still prompting for creds.

Comment: Re-look at what Steve said.  All Kerberos operations, in order to be successful, *require* a unique SPN.  And that SPN must not be a duplicate.  Did you read documentation somewhere which said an SPN is not required due to kernel-mode authentication being turned on?  If so, please share it.

Comment: An SPN is required for Kerberos the protocol to function, period. Windows will register the hostname and FQDN as an SPN on the machine account in AD automatically. Absent an SPN, the Negotiate protocol will fall back to NTLM which does NOT require an SPN. In this case it attempted Kerberos, so checking that the SPN it found matches up to the machine account is critical.

Comment: OK fair comment re: the automatic registration of SPNs. In the working and non-working cases, the SPNs are registered against the machine accounts. Furthermore, setspn -X finds no duplicates. In the end I just built a new server for my purposes and am using that instead of an existing web server. It all works fine. Mysterious. Thanks for all your ideas.

Comment: I think the older WIN2016 Server might have had it's support for some Kerberos encryption types, such as AES256-SHA1, removed.   To check and fix this, in Active Directory, navigate to the computer object (Do not use "Find Computer", you need to actually manually navigate to the object's OU location).  Once on the object, click the Attribute Editor tab (View > Advanced Features if it's not present), then scroll down to msDS-SupportedEncrtyptionTypes.  Ensure that the full value from the 'good' server are copied over to the 'bad' server.

Comment: Thanks for this intriguing suggestion. I checked this attribute for both the non-working and working server and this was set to the same value 0x1C (RC4_HMAC_MD5 | AES128_CTS_HMAS_SHA1_96 | AES256_CTS_HMAS_SHA1_96)